# Multiple Count Statements in a single stament on a same table in sql

Tags: sql

How to combine these two queries into a single query ?  I tried various options but none of them worked.

SQL>

```
select count (*) from tab_proclog_cso where ( to_char(starttime, 'yyyymmddhh24miss') between('20130709000000') and ('20130709010000') );

  COUNT(*)
----------
     28328
```

SQL>

```
select count (*) from tab_proclog_cso where ( to_char(starttime, 'yyyymmddhh24miss') between('20130709010000') and ('20130709020000') );

  COUNT(*)
----------
     14997
```

Comment: So you want a query that return 43325 (28328+14997) ?

Comment: So, if something happened at *exactly* `20130709010000`, you want it included in *both* counts? Usually, if you're working with continuous data such as datetime data, you want to use semi-open intervals with an exclusive endpoint, and so should avoid `BETWEEN` which always treats the range as a closed interval.

Answer (score 1):

```
select 
   sum(case when to_char(starttime, 'yyyymmddhh24miss') between('20130709000000') and ('20130709010000') then 1 else 0 end) as res1
   ,sum(case when to_char(starttime, 'yyyymmddhh24miss') between('20130709000000') and ('20130709010000') then 1 else 0 end) as res2
from tab_proclog_cso
```

Answer (score 0):

you could do a UNION, that will result in 2 rows:

```
select count (*) AS COL from tab_proclog_cso where ( to_char(starttime, 'yyyymmddhh24miss')    
between('20130709000000') and ('20130709010000') )
UNION
select count (*) AS COL from tab_proclog_cso where ( to_char(starttime, 'yyyymmddhh24miss') 
between('20130709010000') and ('20130709020000') )
```

or do 2 computed columns for a single row:

```
SELECT
(select count (*) from tab_proclog_cso where ( to_char(starttime, 'yyyymmddhh24miss')    
between('20130709000000') and ('20130709010000') ) ) AS COL1,
( select count (*) from tab_proclog_cso where ( to_char(starttime, 'yyyymmddhh24miss') 
between('20130709010000') and ('20130709020000') ) ) AS COL2
```

or a total:

```
SELECT
(select count (*) from tab_proclog_cso where ( to_char(starttime, 'yyyymmddhh24miss')    
between('20130709000000') and ('20130709010000') ) ) +
( select count (*) from tab_proclog_cso where ( to_char(starttime, 'yyyymmddhh24miss') 
between('20130709010000') and ('20130709020000') ) ) AS TOTAL
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    select count (*) as count1,(select count (*) from tab_proclog_cso where ( 
to_char(starttime, 'yyyymmddhh24miss') between('20130709010000')
 and ('20130709020000') )) count2 from tab_proclog_cso where ( to_char(starttime,    
'yyyymmddhh24miss') between('20130709000000') and ('20130709010000') );
```

I guess this will work for you